# Move image 2 when hovering image 1

Tags: jquery, mousehover, mouseleave

What I would like to do :

Moving 5px down image 2 when hovering image 1:

[image: image1 with its reflection (image2)]

I don't know code (a little CSS) but I think this one could help to do what I want, of course it's not working, could you tell me why?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.image1').on('mouseenter', function() {
$(".image2").addClass("move5px");
});
});

$('.image1').on('mouseleave', function() {
$(".image2").removeClass("move5px");
});
```

The class I use:

```
.move5px{
   top:-5px
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML and CSS to provide a [working demonstration](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

ok here is the working code (#id names added):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#image1').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $("#image2").addClass("move5px");
  });
  $('#image1').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $("#image2").removeClass("move5px");
  });
});
```

And the css with a transition added for animation :

```
#image2 { transition: 150ms; }
.move5px{
   padding-top:5px; 
}
```